# Is that Flutter need required and late for null safety in sdk version up to 2.7.0?

Tags: flutter, sdk, camera, version, required

In the below code, this code occurs error that `late` and `required` are not available in the flutter version 2.7.0.

```dart
  late CameraController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;  

...

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key? key, required this.imagePath})
      : super(key: key);
```

So, I change the flutter version up to 2.1.2 like this, and solved this problem right away.

```dart
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Is that Flutter need other definition instead of `required` and `late` for null safety in sdk version up to 2.7.0?

If yes, how I changes definition `required` and `late` in sdk version up to 2.7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to:

```dart
  final CameraController _controller;
  final Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;  

...

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, @required this.imagePath})
      : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 0):

This video **"Dart null-safety and how it affects Flutter"**, will make things very clear.

I watched it and now I understand how Dart null-safety affects Flutter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH5tRjXCL14